# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un temporizador que finalice en cero "0"? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero incorporar un temporizador de 15 segundos. Mi objetivo es que al finalizar dichos segundos el TextView del temporizador muestre un "0" en lugar de un "1".

```
private int seconds;
private long timeLeftInMilliseconds = 16000;
```

Metodo startTimer:

```
public void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds =l;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }

    }.start();
    timerRunning=true;
}
```

Metodo UpdateTimer

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void updateTimer(){
    seconds = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds % 60000 / 1000;
    String timeLeftText;
    timeLeftText = "";
    timeLeftText += seconds;
    show_time.setText(timeLeftText);

    timerRunning=false;
}
```

Comment: Probe tu codigo y finalza en 0, asegurate de que no estes modificando tu variable seconds en alguna otra parte

Comment: Me parece muy interesante porque no hayo la forma de que me salga en cero
el TextView se detiene cuando está en 1, tendré entonces que hacer un if para imprimir un "0" no es la mejor opción pero no veo de otra, tendria que hacer que ese if se demore 1 segundo imprimiendo el 0 en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

La solución que planteas resuelve, pero en cambio puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma, queda un código mas limpio

```
public void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new.CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds =l;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = 0;
            updateTimer();           
         }

}.start();
timerRunning=true;
```